# How can I filter out a ROLAP pattern on SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, olap-cube

How to remove a pattern from a 'CUBE' query:

I have this query:

```
select  
    coalesce(left(k.SubCodiceStab,12),'AUSL_TOTALE') as Stabilimento, 
    1.0 * sum(k.PotenzialmenteInappropriato) / (count(k.Progr) - sum(k.PotenzialmenteInappropriato)) as Rapporto,
    coalesce(DescrDisciplina,'TOT. STABILIMENTO') AS Disciplina,
    coalesce(K.TipoDRG,'TOT. DRG') as TipoDRG,
    anno
from 
    my_table k
where 
    k.Mese in (1,2)
group by 
    SubCodiceStab, DescrDisciplina, TipoDRG, anno with cube
```

I don't need to take out the 'cumulative total' over multiple years for the single Disciplina, but I still want to be able to do the 'Grand'cumulative.

this is an exeplum of the my query result (I, by now, don't have 2017 but will be added soon):

```
Stabilimento Rapporto             Disciplina TipoDRG  anno
------------ ------------------- ---------- -------- -----------
(#)AUSL_TOT. 0.225806451612       AUSL_TOT   TOT. DRG NULL
AUSL_TOTALE  0.000000000000       AUSL_TOT   C        NULL
AUSL_TOTALE  0.229508196721       AUSL_TOT   M        NULL
04           0.000000000000       ASTAN      C        2018
04           0.000000000000       ASTAN      C        NULL
04           0.229508196721       ASTAN      M        2018
04           0.229508196721       ASTAN      M        NULL
04           0.225806451612       ASTAN      TOT. DRG 2018
(*)04        0.225806451612       ASTAN      TOT. DRG NULL
```

I'd like to remove the last line without the possibility of having the 'GRAND TOTAL'. Basically I still need row (#) [what I think is the empty pattern] but I also want to discard row (*).

In general terms I would remove a specific pattern from the cube (without affecting other patterns)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on the group you're excluding here, but some combination of `HAVING` and/or `GROUPING()`/`GROUPING_ID()` should do it.